# How to get second version of the same app from XCode?

Tags: iphone, ios, version, xcode4.2

I have one iPhone with the name of `"Sample"` in my device. I did some changes on the app for the version two. I want to install the `"Sample1.1."`(Second Version) app in my device without deletion or replace of first one. I have did below steps,

```
1. Changed the Product Name "Sample" to "Sample1.1"
2. Changed the ipa file Name "Sample" to "Sample1.1"
```

I have tried these steps, when i trag the "Sample1.1" ipa to iTunes the "Sample1.1" replaced with the "Sample" app. I want to install these two app in my device. What are the changes i need to do in XCode? Can you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks to all for your valuable answers. I hope below all answers will work very fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the name that makes the difference, it's the bundle ID in your app's plist file.

Change that, and then you can install two copies of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new target in Xcode, which will give you a second info.plist file. In your second info.plist you can change the app name and bundle ID. you can now compile either app from the same source and install them both on the same device without needing to do any manual editing after you compile.

Answer (score 1):

Click on your project, then there will be project and targets, you can easily duplicate the current "Sample" and make it "Sample1.1". Next to "Run" button, you can select your "Sample1.1" and build it, it will install as different version

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different provisioning profile. Then in setting uncheck the automatically manage signing option and chose the profile you added for signing.